# GeoServer option "followline" results in no labels on a river layer

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I'm using GeoServer 2.10.1 with a river layer and I'm trying to add labels which follow the lines. (The river layer is sourced from a PostGreSQL table if that makes a difference.)

Using the [line with default label](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#id13) SLD, the rivers are labelled:

[image]

But when I use the [label following line](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#id15) example (which includes the `<VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>` parameter), the labels disappear:

```
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
       <TextSymbolizer>
         <Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </Label>
         <LabelPlacement>
           <LinePlacement />
         </LabelPlacement>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
       </TextSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Is this due to the complexity of the rivers, or is there another issue occurring here?

Comment: did you add the ` <LabelPlacement>
           <LinePlacement />
         </LabelPlacement>` section too?

Comment: @IanTurton I edited the question to clarify that I'm using the exact example from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#id15 - unsuccessfully

Comment: (the field name `name` is correct for this layer, and works with default line placement as shown in the screenshot)

Comment: do they come back when you zoom in - if so it is complexity

Comment: if I zoom in so that a single vertex-to-vertex segment is visible, the labels show, so it looks like I've reached a complexity limitation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With followLine there is a "maxAngleDelta" check that will prevent labels from being placed when the angle of two subsequent characters is too high, so much that it would break the label or have it overlap with itself.
Try playing with it and see if that helps:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#maxangledelta